# Return old value from setter w/o temp variable using finally

Tags: java, finally

I was implementing the `V setValue(V value)` method in `Map.Entry<K,V>` and have done the following:

```
@Override public T setValue(T value) {
  try {
    return this.value;
  } finally {
    this.value = value;
  }
}
```

It works as it should.

I know there are some questions about `finally` blocks and stuff, but I couldn't find this specific question. What are *your* thoughts on this particular use-case? Is this legal? Should be avoided? If yes then why or why not. Thanks!

Comment: Interesting pattern - to obfuscate the code. Only the title of the question tells us, what the code is actually doing ;) (Honestly - I had to read Tom's and Jon's translations first to see what's happening)

Comment: note: the compiler is still creating a temporary (hidden) variable in that code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Prefer simple, obvious code. i.e.

```
@Override public T setValue(T value) {
    T old = this.value;
    this.value = value;
    return old;
}
```

Also, this can be extended to be [locally] thread-safe (as NIO `attach`).

```
private final AtomicReference<T> valueRef;

@Override public T setValue(T value) {
    return valueRef.getAndSet(value);
}
```

Comment: Great usage of `AtomicReference`!

Comment: @Psycho_Dad NIO actually uses `AtomicReferenceFieldUpdater` in `attach` because the common usage is to set the value once and read back multiple times. Using the updater means that each `SelectionKey` (??) doesn't need to carry around an `AtomicReference`.

Answer (score 3):

It works, but it's not nearly as obvious (easy to understand) as:

```
@Override public T setValue(T value) {
  T oldValue = this.value;
  this.value = value;
  return oldValue;
}
```

Why not use this simpler form?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think that, by the moment, it's absolutely legal. Normally you use the finally clause to specify values that execute o are assigned just before the return. But sometimes we use to put inside the return, and a warning is thrown. I think you must avoid that return, but you can use the finally for the rest.

Otherwise, it is like an obsolete function, for example, and it does no matter if you put those assignments inside the finally or after the try/catch block.